# WinRT HttpClient `Connection: Upgrade`

Tags: c#, .net, http, windows-8, windows-runtime

I need to set `Connection` header of my http request to be `Upgrade`. I'm using `HttpClient` class.  I've tried

```
HttpClient connection < .... >
connection.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", new string[]{"Upgrade"});
```

and

```
connection.DefaultRequestHeaders.Connection.Add("Upgrade");
```

But my Fiddler proxy shows me that my request's `Connection` is `Keep-Alive`. I tried some other values (just to test a behavior) and figured out that no `Connection` values except `Close` do get into request.

Comment: No values of `Connection` except of `Close` are mentioned in appropriate RFC (HTTP 1.1)

Comment: What protocol are you trying to upgrade to?  `upgrade` is a valid token according to HTTPbis http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p1-messaging-25#section-6.7  however, it should be used alongside the `Upgrade` to list the supported protocols.  It is possible that when you set the upgrade header, internally the connection value will be changed.

Comment: I need to upgrade to websocket `ws:` protocol. My connection is a handshake one. I set `Upgrade` header field to `websocket` value. But `Connection` is `Keep-Alive` anyway.

Comment: I've just & checked figured out that `Connection` and `Upgrade` fields assignment order makes no sense.

Comment: Do you know that the HttpBaseProtocolFilter actually supports WebSockets? Or are you planning on implementing the websocket support yourself?

Comment: Also, simply assigning `Upgrade: websocket` does not change `Connection` value.

Comment: I have a websocket implementation (i've ported Websocket4Net and socket.io to WinRT). I just need to make a handshake.

Comment: I wondered that this question has 13 views only while having some really popular tags assigned.

I've implemented js/C# interop via WebView and used js socket.io library. But the original question remains unresolved.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the SignalR WinRT client.  That might give you some clues as they probably use WebSockets.